# why can't we pass string in java constructor

Tags: java, constructor, copy-constructor

```
class td{    
    int roll;    
    float per;    
    String name;   

    td(int r,float p,String n){    
        roll=r;    
        name=n;    
        per=p;    
    }

    td(){       
        roll=0;    
        name="sachin";    
        per=0;    
    }

    void get(){    
        try{    
            DataInputStream x=new DataInputStream(System.in);    
            roll=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());    
            per=Float.parseFloat(x.readLine());    
            name=x.readLine();    
        }    
        catch(Exception e){    
            System.out.println("the error is" +e);    
        }    
    }

    void disp(){    
        System.out.println(roll);    
        System.out.println(name);    
        System.out.println(per);    
    }

}



class std{    
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        td c1 = new  td();    
        td c2 = new  td(3,5.600,"ddd");    
        td c3 = new  td();

        c1.disp();    
        c2.disp();    
        c3.disp();    
    }

}
```

When i run this code I got this :

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.0\bin\std.java:48: cannot resolve symbol   
   symbol  : constructor td  (int,double,java.lang.String)
   location: class td
   td c2 = new  td(3,5.600,"ddd");
        ^

   Note: C:\j2sdk1.4.0\bin\std.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -deprecation for details.
   1 error

   Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Side note : class names should start with capital.

Comment: "C:\j2sdk1.4.0\bin" -- by the way, do you really need to use a java version from the last millenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check your error, it's not because of `String`, but it's due to the `Double`.

You need to call constructor as below :

```
td c2 = new td(3,5.600F,"ddd");
```

Because by default `5.600` is considered a `Double`, so the compiler tries to search for **(int,double,java.lang.String)** but it does not exist, so it generates an error.

Comment: YUP I GOT THAT THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

5.600 is considered as `double`, not `float`.

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F
>   or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the
>   letter D or d.

Since you didn't append the `f`, it's searching for a constructor `td(int r,double p,String n)` which you didn't provide for your class and hence the error.

You need to precise a float argument by appending a `f` to 5.600.

I.e :

```
td c2 = new td(3,5.600f,"ddd");
```

Answer (score 0):

td c2 = new  td(3,5.600,"ddd");

The variables declared in the td class does not match the data entered
Replace the float type for a Double.